# Linear algebra algorithms example

Tags: linear-algebra

Where does linear algebra been used in programming? I read about google algorithms of searching. Can you post me some examples? Maybe also in C language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear Algebra is the back-bone of any discipline... Applications listed by @Jason justify that. However, the list is not exhaustive.

I would like to share a basic application:

When search engines find similar pages, Pages can be considered as vectors, and the angle between them represents the similarity (measures projection of 1 page to another). Lower is the angle between 2 vectors, higher is the similarity.

Isn't it cool ???

Answer (score 2):

Here are *some* programming applications of linear algebra:

- [Game theory](http://web.mit.edu/lhoang/www/GameSolver.html)
- Managing inventories
- Communications systems
- Ecological systems of interactions between animals
- Statistical correlations
- Voting probabilities
- Markov chains
- Transition probabilities from one state to another (i.e. disease)
- Transportation network
- Many applications in optimization using [linear programming](http://jean-pierre.moreau.pagesperso-orange.fr/c_linear.html).